# SPSS Populate Scratch Variable with Standard Deviation

Tags: spss

I am just learning SPSS, I have a background in PL/SQL and T-SQL

I have a dataset and need to make three groups based on deviation from the mean for a specific variable

Greater than 1 Standard Deviation Above the Mean

Greater than 1 Standard Deviation Below the Mean

All Others

I wanted to use a scratch variable but have no idea how to find the standard deviation of an existing variable and populate it into a scratch variable to use for my grouping conditions.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate command can calculate the SD of a variable and add it to the dataset, like this:

```
aggregate/outfile=* mode=addvariables/break= 
        /SDyourvar=sd(yourvar) /MEANyourvar=mean(yourvar).
```

Now you can use the variables to create groups like this for example:

```
do if yourvar < (MEANyourvar - SDyourvar).
   compute group=-1.
else if yourvar > (MEANyourvar + SDyourvar).
   compute group=1.
else.
   compute group=0.
end if.
```

Or for a shorter version:

```
compute group=(yourvar > (MEANyourvar+SDyourvar)) - (yourvar < (MEANyourvar-SDyourvar)).
```

Comment: Ok I updated you cod slightly as follows


AGGREGATE /OUTFILE =* OVERWRITE=YES MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK= 
        /SDhealth=SD(Health) /MEANhealth=MEAN(Health).
DO IF Health < (MEANhealth - SDhealth).
   COMPUTE HealthGroup=-1.
ELSE IF Health > (MEANhealth + SDhealth).
   COMPUTE HealthGroup=1.
ELSE.
   COMPUTE HealthGroup=0.
END IF.


Works great however it creates variables in the data set for SDhealth MEANhealth and HealthGroup


I would like SDhealth and MEANhealth to be in scratch variables to keep my data set cleaner, is this possible?

Comment: alas, you can't define a scratch variable in `aggregate`. But you can delete these variables after you use them (after running `execute.`): `delete vars var1 var2.`